# MySQL query between 2 lat, long giving different number than PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this php code:

```
$lat1 = 39.210637;
$lng1 = -105.534551;
$lat2 = 39.725865;
$lng2 = -105.016820;

$theta = $lng1 - $lng2;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);

$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

$kilometers = $miles * 1.60934;

$meters = $kilometers * 1000;
```

returns: 72503 meters

and I tried to code it exactly the same in MySQL:

```
ROUND((RADIANS(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(39.210637)) * SIN(RADIANS(39.725865)) + COS(RADIANS(39.210637)) * COS(RADIANS(39.725865)) * COS(RADIANS(-105.534551 - (-105.016820)))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000)
```

returns: 22 meters

Why is that, aren't they supposed to be the same functions? Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, looks like I missed one rad2deg which should be DEGREES() in MySQL, so the code should be:

```
ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(39.210637)) * SIN(RADIANS(39.725865)) + COS(RADIANS(39.210637)) * COS(RADIANS(39.725865)) * COS(RADIANS(-105.534551 + 105.016820))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000)
```

Now it works right.